# List of months without tables SQL UNION in WHILE loop

Tags: mysql, sql, while-loop, union

I want create one table with first column - month ,second - days in month.
Now I have this working in MySQL 5.7.13 code:

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_loop()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x INT;

 SET x = 1;

 SELECT MONTHNAME(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)) AS 'Month',
DAY(LAST_DAY(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1))) AS 'Days in Month';

 WHILE x  < 12 DO

SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD((MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)),
INTERVAL x MONTH)) AS 'Month',

DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD((MAKEDATE (YEAR(CURDATE()),1)),
INTERVAL x MONTH))) AS 'Days in Month';

SET  x = x + 1;
END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I want consider all 12 SELECTs in one table, how I can do this?

Note: i should do this without creating any tables.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: MySQL 5.7.13 through terminal on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Insert the generated data into a temporary table, and just select all records from this table at the end.

Comment: @Shadow sorry for my not precisely formulated question, but i should do this without creating any tables, including temporary tables

Comment: Then generate the the sql command as string with unions between the selects and execute the huge union with a prepared statement.